# How to make WordPress site accessible via both domain name and IP address?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, webserver, redirect

I've a WordPress site which needs to be accessible via both public domain name and IP address as well. It needs to behave exactly the same when accessed from any.

I tried adding IP as server alias bit that seem to work for home page only.

```
ServerName site.local
ServerAlias www.site.local
ServerAlias 127.0.0.10
```

When traversing pages, it redirects to server name instead of server alias I added.

Since WP stores site url and home url in database itself, I think it priorities it.

Is there any way I can make this thing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants in wp-config.php based on what `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` is.

That will take care of a lot, but if you have hardcoded links to http://example.com/mypage/, those will not be rewritten to http://10.10.10.10/ when accessed via IP. If you require that, you'll probably have to use an output handler that changes the output after it has been generated.