# Use WordPress site as IP only until the domain is available

Tags: wordpress, apache, digital-ocean

I have a page where I cannot own the domain currently as the domain is **not yet free to buy**. But I need to create the new WordPress site already.

So the WordPress **page** is already **available via IP**. But as you can see from the image, it tries to connect to the final domain.

How can I use the WordPress page via IP only, until I finally own the domain?

For info, I use [DigitalOcean WordPress Droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-wordpress-one-click-install-on-digitalocean-2). This is a preconfigured setup for running WordPress on Ubuntu.

I already tried to:

- edit Apache vhost config
- edit WordPress config
- edits hosts file

without success.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated the site URL in settings? Have you checked if the domain appears in any records in the database? There are quite a few similar questions here which should help, have you seen those? Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535534/wordpress-host-ip-changed,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702743/how-to-make-wordpress-site-accessible-via-both-domain-name-and-ip-address ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress host IP changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535534/wordpress-host-ip-changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the URL is written directly into the database. The best way is now to connect to MySQL and change the domain directly there:

1. log into the SSH session of your server
2. type `mysql` to access MySQL
3. now you can use `SHOW DATABASES;` to select the proper database in the next step

   in my case, it's called `wordpress`
4. to get into the database, type `USE wordpress;`
5. to see the current URL type `Select * from wp_options where option_name IN('siteurl','home');`

   for me it's `http://159.89.***.***`
6. now we can overwrite both with

   `update wp_options set option_value='http://www.shop123.com' where option_name = 'siteurl';`

   and

   `update wp_options set option_value='http://www.shop123.com' where option_name = 'home';`
7. and leave with `exit`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few easy methods to change the Site URL manually. Any of the methods will work.

It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where “127.0.0.1” is the correct IP address of your site.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://127.0.0.1' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://127.0.0.1' );
```

Comment: Sadly does not change anything. Still using the domain. Not sure where the domain was set in the DigitalOcean setup. Also did a `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Comment: So I just found out that the `wp-config.php` is ignored. My solution was to go to `/wp-admin/options.php` that worked. And here set the `siteurl` and `home` to the IP.

Comment: wp-config is never ignored, there are many different supported methods for setting the site url, if you don't have the technical ability to implement my described method then use another

Comment: Well I added these both lines and restarted apache. But nothing happened. So what I did wrong? Maybe for someone else having this issue in the future.

Comment: don't know, don't care, but for the clarity of others so that they are not mislead wp-config file is never ignored as it is the main configuration file in wordpress, supported methods of changing site url are detailed on the official wordpress website https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/